# jQuery datepicker doesn't appear in Firefox

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an input form using FLAT UI KIT that MUST contain a datepicker, so I chose to use jQuery's widget. But when I run it in Chrome the datepicker shows up, whilet on Firefox it is shows as a simple text input.
Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test &middot; stuff with datepicker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Loading Flat UI -->
    <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <!--  my addition jQuery UI for datepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flatui-checkbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flatui-radio.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>                

    <style>
           .containerx {
        background-color: #1abc9c;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: bottom right;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        }      
        .titluedit{
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        font-size:14px;
        }

        .titlueditx{
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        font-size:14px;
        color:red;
        }

        fieldset { margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
    </style>

    <script>
    </script>

    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(function() {
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                });    
            });    

    </script>    

  </head>
  <body>
  <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="logox" height="81" width="305"> 
        <h1 class="demo-panel-title" style="text-align:center; color:#d35400">XXXXXXXXX</h1>
        <h3 class="demo-panel-title" style="text-align:center; color:#1abc9c">New info</h3>

       <div class="container" style="width:900px; margin:0 auto;"> 
<form action="save.php" method="post">
            <div class="container" style="width:700px; margin:0 auto;"> 
                    <fieldset>
                    <p class="titlueditx">Name *:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="nume" value="" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <p class="titlueditx">Medium time *:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="durata" value="" placeholder="minutes" class="form-control" />
                    </fieldset>

                        <p class="titlueditx">Start date  *:</p>
                        <input type="date" id="ui-datepicker" name="dataang" value="" class="form-control"/><br>

                    <fieldset>
                        <p class="titlueditx">Some other stuff *:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="sefutzul" value="" placeholder="Other relevant stuff" class="form-control" />
                    </fieldset>

            </div>

  <br><br>
    <div class="container" style="width:700px; margin:0 auto;"> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>      
                    <input type="hidden" id="idhidfirma" name="idfirma" value="1" />       
                    <input type="hidden" id="idhnumefirma" name="numefirma" value="xxxxx" />       
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-hg btn-primary">        Save info      </button>  

</form>
                </td>
        <td>  
            <form action="mylist.php" method="post">                    
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="idfirma" value="1">                     
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="numefirma" value="xxxxx">             
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-hg btn-danger">              Cancel            </button>  
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
           </table>
      </div>
    </div>      



</body></html>
```

What can I do to make it work in Firefox TOO?

Also in Chrome how can I make the calendar to close onClick on a day? Right now the calendar stays shown until i click somewhere else on the screen.

Comment: Can you provide a demo of the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Yup... this is sort of a demo of what my problem is. I did not include bootstrap.js into it, but the behavior is still the same http://jsfiddle.net/ZFJc6/ , So try accessing the fiddle from firefox, then from chrome. In chrome the date edit is going to show a datepicker while firefox will show only a simple text input box

Comment: Or better yet (a more stripped version) http://jsfiddle.net/ZFJc6/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not Firefox, you are defining:

1. an input type=date with id `ui-datepicker`
2. binding a jQuery UI datepicker to an id `datepicker`

The 2nd selector not match any element so the jQuery UI datepicker is not binded to anything; by using an input type=date Chrome renders automatically a calendar control, so you see a calendar in Chrome because of the input type (see. https://plus.google.com/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/hTcMLVNKnec)

To fix the issue in all browser you can set input type=text in your `ui-datepicker` element, and set the correct selector.

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#ui-datepicker").datepicker();
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zAKQe/

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code that I placed in jsfiddle was the result of 2 separate tests combined into one code... I overlooked the id :(. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Date picker is working with firefox, but `z-index` of datepicker is in "-". So it's not appearing in firefix browser. 
Show update the `z-index` of datepicker through jquery it will appear.

```
$(".datepicker").css("z-index","100");
```

Answer (score 1):

it will work on mozila firefox  if is not working update your firefox version .
i run this it works. thanks

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Datepicker fadein</title>
  <link  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({showAnim: "fadeIn"});
        })
 </script>
```

in your body of the page use the  input

```
<input class="datepicker">
```